# Run (%run) Python 2.7+ notebook with a 3.0+ print (print()) gives an error (SyntaxError)

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

In my 2.7 Python Jupyter (IPython) notebook there are 3.0+ version print lines (print()) => OK. 
If I run (%run) a notebook file in another one, the same print-line gives a strange error.
What can be the problem here?

print.ipynb:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print("Loading ... ",end="")
```

> ```
> Loading ...
> ```

master.ipynb:

```
%run "print.ipynb"
```

...

> ```
>      File "<ipython-input-2-33ed49807c0a>", line 2
>      print("Loading ... ",end="")
>                              ^
>      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: Looks like it's not loading the `print` function for some reason.

Comment: without the end argument, it works.

Comment: Right; it's invalid syntax for Python 2's `print` statement, which should have been replaced with Python 3's `print` function via the `import` statement, but that doesn't seem to have been executed properly.